# Does the gdb command "info source" give valid information about the compilation flags?

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, flags

I typed `info source` while using gdb and here is what I got :

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is code.cpp
Compilation directory is ~/dev/Code
Located in ~/dev/Code/code.cpp
Contains 8 lines.
Source language is c++.
Producer is GNU C++14 9.3.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

but I was surprised to see this line which seems to indicate the flags I apparently used when I compiled the sources :

```
Producer is GNU C++14 9.3.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection
```

I'm sure I didn't use any of these flags except `-g` tho. Do you think these flags are used by default ? Is it possible to unactivate them ?

Comment: as `-Wall` wouldn't effect the compiled output I guess gcc doesn't bother storing it in the debug info, the flags that are stored seem likely to be defaults, you can change them by using different values for those options

Comment: You're right, I used the flag `-std=c++17` and it was displayed ! `Producer is GNU C++17 9.3.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -std=c++17 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection.`

Comment: If you give your GCC command the `-###` (three sharp signs) option, do the flags that it outputs match the flags that GDB’s `info source` command outputs?